# How find this sequence $a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $a_{1}=\dfrac{1}{3}$,and such that
$$a_{n+1}=2a_{n}-[a_{n}]$$
where $[x]$  greatest integer less than equal to “x”
find $a_{2010}+a_{2011}$

for this Problem I can use  Mathematical induction: we have
$$a_{2n}=n-\dfrac{1}{3}, a_{2n+1}=n+\dfrac{1}{3}$$

can you someone not use Mathematical induction methods?

my idea use 
$$a_{n}-1<[a_{n}]\le a_{n}$$

then  How can we have
$$a_{n+1}=pa_{n}+(-1)^{n}?$$

Comment: How is the very end of the post ("How can we have...") related to the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Sinse the sequence is defined via recursion, the use of induction in showing properties of the sequence seems virtually unavoidable.